# How to replace "/" in column name with "_" in dbt code

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have some column names with "/" in between, for example /CPM/PRIORITY,/CPM/TASK and I want to create views with column name _CPM_PRIORITY,_CPM_TASK, is there any way to achieve it? By the way, I don't want to hard-code the name in the sql, thanks in advance